# Can I create multiple instances of Realtime Database Firebase?

Tags: php, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create multiple instances of Realtime Database on Firebase using PHP SDK but can't find it anywhere.
When I get a new client, it needs to create a lot of things, and create a new instance of firebase realtime database is one of these actions.
So I want to create a robot to make it via PHP SDK.

I hope I made myself clear.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

According to Jérôme, the creator of kreait library, it is not possible to do this via PHP SDK.
It is only possible to do it via REST API